# Testflight's External testing is asking for new build

Tags: app-store, testflight

My app has passed Apple's review and the status is "Pending Developer Release".

Yesterday, I was able to add Internal testers for the latest build 0.0.3 (which is approved by Apple).

Today I am trying to add external testers but I am not able to, because I am getting this error

> The value for the CFBundleShortVersionString key in the app's Info.plist file must be higher than 0.0.3.

How to add external testers?

Comment: google's infra for developers is seriously better than apple

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  I'm having the exact same problem where I can't release to external testers (even though I _could_ release to the app store if I wanted to) and where no earlier build number ever got uploaded.